# Reopen queue: can't choose "Leave closed" as "doesn't meet a Stack Overflow guideline"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, user-interface, reopen-review

It seems that in the Reopen Votes queue it is not possible to choose "Leave closed" with a community-specific reason:

- choose "Leave closed" -> "Submit"
- popup opens
- choose "This question doesn't meet a Stack Overflow guideline."
- choose any sub-reason (the radio button is clearly selected)
- click "Keep closed"

An error banner appears, that says:

> You must select a reason before submitting.

Any amount of toggling the other radios, or switching back and forth within the dialog, doesn't help. At this point I can only go back and choose another reason to leave closed.

[image: Screenshot of the error notification above the modal with the leave closed reasons]

Comment: wait... Why does it require selecting a reason, if it's not casting a new close vote?

Comment: For some reason it only works if you've selected something in the first page of reasons. So, the general, rather than community reasons. Also, there is a bunch of errors in the console about too much recursion when the modal changes - clicking the option that brings you to the community reasons, or going back to the general ones, or closing the dialog.

Comment: @KevinB if you're complaining that it shouldn't require a close reason, [this ship](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release) has sailed. If you're wondering what are the actual use cases for all this: the "Leave closed" reason appears in the close banner below the notice that the post has been reviewed for reopening and left closed (specifics in the Meta.SE thread). It's useful when the original close reason is blatantly incorrect, or when some edit does resolve the original closure but fails to make the question on-topic for another reason.

Comment: @KevinB If you agree with the current close reason, you can select _"Original close reason(s) were not resolved."_. If you disagree with the existing close reason, or the original close reason was resolved, but there are still other reasons to keep it closed, you can select another close reason. When one other reviewer (I think) chooses the same alternative close reason and the review ends, it will add this reason to the closed question banner in the section about the outcome of the review.

Comment: Possibly related to [this bug I reported on Arqade a while back](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16556/185203)

Comment: I've also been seeing this. Disabling user-scripts (often the first thing I try when getting such bugs) doesn't help. Also, it happens on both PC (Windows/Edge) and Mobile (Android/Samsung).

Comment: Potentially also related (MSE): [On some sites the "Leave Closed Reasons" dialog is missing the second page, for reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382389/335251)

Comment: Me too: https://imgur.com/a/ivCfwWq @ https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/33496232  I switched my selection to opinion-based and it worked.

Comment: I have the same issue. This is a bug that's causing me to stop going through the review queue.

Comment: I came across the same bug today.

Comment: I have also encountered this bug. I am using Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: Still reproduces (Linux, Brave and Firefox).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[I did this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16622/296606)

This past December I added several checks to our reopen queue modal in an effort to resolve a bug. That bug allowed a `Leave Closed` vote in the reopen queue to be cast after selecting `This question doesn't meet a [Community] guideline` without selecting an actual community specific reason in the following modal.

This bug was introduced with this specific change:

> I have also updated the leave closed modal so that it clears your reason and your community specific reason upon exiting so that there is always a clean slate when you open the modal.

Resetting the state of the modal allowed for a race condition where the first modal selection could be cleared before submitting the community-specific reason which is why the error produced was `You must select a reason before submitting.` and not `You must select a community specific reason before submitting.`

As of today, this issue should be resolved. I'm sorry for any inconvenience this issue has caused and would like to thank you for your patience while we resolved this issue.